# How to access paragraph element inside class element using ondrop event and delete it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two div box: .box001, .box002.

I want to delete the p element with name1, name2, name3 on each drop.

When I drag and drop .box002 with id="1" to another div - .box001 with id="10" dragged element deletes ondrop also background-color becomes none, likewise box002 with id="2" to box001 with id="20" and third box similary.

How can I achieve this?

```js
function allowDrop(ev)
{
  ev.preventDefault();
}
function drag(ev)
{
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}
function drop(ev)
{
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  alert(data);
  var el = document.getElementById(data);

  el.parentNode.removeChild(el);    // deleting drag item

  ev.target.style.backgroundColor = 'initial'; //[value indicate which box elemenet] bgcoclor none
  document.getElementsByClassName(ev.target.className).innerHTML = '';  // which box p  should blank 
}
```

```css
.box001 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10%;
  background-color: #42e0fd;
  font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font: 70px;
  ;
  color: #001a00;
  font-size: xx-small;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
}

.box002 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box001" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10">
  <p id="11"> name1</p>
</div>
<div class="box001" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="20">
  <p id="12">name1</p>
</div>
<div class="box001" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="30">
  <p id="13">name1</p>
</div>


<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="1">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" draggable="true" id="1" style="width:50px; height:50px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded" />
</div>
<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" draggable="true" id="2" style="width:50px; height:50px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded" />
</div>
<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" draggable="true" id="3" style="width:50px; height:50px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I added is at the bottom of the Javascript container. Hope this helps.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  alert(data);
  var el = document.getElementById(data);

  el.parentNode.removeChild(el); // deleting drag item

  ev.target.style.backgroundColor = 'initial'; //[value indicate which box elemenet] bgcoclor none
  
  /* Added */
  var pParagraph = ev.target.firstElementChild;
  console.log(pParagraph);
  ev.target.removeChild(pParagraph);
}
```

```css
.box001 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10%;
  background-color: #42e0fd;
  font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font: 70px;
  ;
  color: #001a00;
  font-size: xx-small;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
}

.box002 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box001" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10">
  <p id="11"> name1</p>
</div>
<div class="box001" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="20">
  <p id="12">name1</p>
</div>
<div class="box001" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="30">
  <p id="13">name1</p>
</div>


<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="1">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" draggable="true" id="1" style="width:50px; height:50px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded" />
</div>
<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" draggable="true" id="2" style="width:50px; height:50px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded" />
</div>
<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" draggable="true" id="3" style="width:50px; height:50px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded" />
</div>
```